# AsyncIO appears to be slower than multithreaded even if tasks are only bound to I/O

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I am creating 8000 text files and writing 100 bytes of data to each file in both asyncio and multithread version. I was expecting asyncio version of the code to be completed before multithread version of the code , as all tasks related to I/O bound and I have understood that asyncio will perform better but the situation is other way around. Asyncio is not only perfroming slow but it is also taking more space than the thread version of the code.

I must be doing something wrong, I have tried it to find where I am lacking in my code but didn't found as such.

`Async IO Version`

```
import time

import aiofiles
import asyncio
from  timeit import timeit
DATA="A"*100
async def write_file(filename_plus_path):
    async with aiofiles.open(filename_plus_path,"w") as f:
        await f.write(DATA)

async  def main():
    coro = [asyncio.create_task(write_file(f"./file/text{i}.txt")) for i in range(8000)]
    await coro[-1]
st = time.time()
print("Started at:",time.strftime("%X"))
asyncio.run(main())
print("Finished at:",time.strftime("%X"))
res = time.time() - st
final_res = res * 1000
print('Execution time:', final_res, 'milliseconds')
```

`Output:`

```
Started at: 16:15:39
Finished at: 16:15:44
Execution time: 4243.027448654175 milliseconds
```

`Multithread Version`

```
import time

import threading
DATA="A"*100
def write_file(filename_plus_path):
   with open(filename_plus_path,"w") as f:
        f.write(DATA)


print("Started at:",time.strftime("%X"))
st = time.time()
thrs=[threading.Thread(target=write_file,args=(f"./file/text{i}.txt",)) for i in range(8000)]
for th in thrs:
    th.start()
for th in thrs:
    th.join()
# print("Finished at:",time.strftime("%X"))
res = time.time() - st
final_res = res * 1000
print('Execution time:', final_res, 'milliseconds')
print("Finished at:",time.strftime("%X"))
```

`output:`

```
Started at: 16:16:57
Execution time: 3494.1318035125732 milliseconds
Finished at: 16:17:01
```

Answer (score 4):

File access in Python `aiofiles` is not proper "single-thread async": it just use multi-threading under the hood - by default, the a `ThreadPoolExecutor` as provided by default by the async module.

A "real" asyncio file thing should use selectors -and for Linux, there are some libraries based on the new `IO_Uring` async file access.

That said, the CPU bound overhead of writing 100 bytes  overwhelms any gain one would get of telling the O.S. to store 100 bytes in a file - keep in mind that the least amount of bytes that will touch the "disk surface" will be 4096 in most scenarios.

Anyway, your answer officially is: `aiofiles` async file implementation uses multi-threading under the hood, with extra limitations due to the use of a default `TheadPoolExecutor` (I think the number of worker threads equal the number of CPU-Cores)  -

You will likely get different results, no guarantees for what side of it :-), using a `io_uring` based async file writing library (or a selector based one),and meaningful quantities of bytes to each file - say, starting from 1MB.

Comment: If I am not bothering you I would like 2nd para in more detail as I am finding it difficult to  understand. Thanks for your understanding in advance.

Comment: 3rd para not 2nd para.

Comment: I mean: 100 bytes is a irrelevant payload if one thinks the amount of time it would take to be flushed to the disk. A program will take more time, _far_ more time, preparing the system call, and moving those bytes around than actually waiting for the O.S. to say "ok, I wrote those 100 bytes to the file"

Comment: why asynio is taking is more space than multi thread ?